# Textures appear fine Shading Mode, but Flat in Render and Render Mode

Tags: rendering, shaders

I am using Blender 3.6.0 LTS, and I am not able to render my textures properly. In Shading mode Textures are rendered fine, when in Render Mode, Textuers are rendering Flat. Pls Provide any Solution.

textures coming fine in shaded mode.
[image]

textures not coming fine in render mode.
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yes Sending the file.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=wDjYmQED" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wDjYmQED/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the *From Instancer* option of the *Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Redrust Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).